# "yarn start" for React Native app fails with "Unable to start server"

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg

When I execute yarn start within my React Native app project folder I get this error:

> yarn run v1.3.2
>   $ react-native-scripts start
>   21:58:08: Unable to start server
>   See https://git.io/v5vcn for more information, either install watchman or run the following snippet:
>     sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=5242880
>     sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=524288
>
> error Command failed with exit code 1.
>   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After I executed the two commands - `sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=5242880` and `sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=524288` - from the error message `yarn start` worked liked expected.